# What are Html fixtures for jasmine unit testing jquery/javascript code and unit testing for jsp pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, maven, jsp, jasmine

Can anyone explain me what are html fixtures in simple language.I am starting and trying to jasmine unit test a jquery/javascript file which is implementing logic for the Jsp file on the front end.The whole project is java as back-end and javascript/jsp as front end.And also if anyone could explain if there is any way we can also unit test jsp code?

Comment: I would assume a html fixture is the html element necessary for your test.  Such as if the method you are testing tests the click interaction of a button which should affect another textarea, the fixture would consist of that button and the textarea.  I could be wrong about that definition.  As far as unit testing jsp code, imho, you don't.  I would say you would jasmine test your javascript, and in regards to your jsp logic, the test for that logic would reside in your functional/integration testing.

Comment: Functional/Integration testing being a suite of tests which run through your application just like a user would, performing operation paths and verifying that the system behaves as is expected, both for the good paths and bad paths.

Comment: Thank you for the response :) It helped a lot.